# Linkedin JavaScript SDK SDK: Cannot read property 'Function' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linkedin-api, server-side-rendering

I am initializing the JavaScript API and most of the time it gives me a `Cannot read property 'Function' of undefined`. I don't know if this helps but it is on the lines calling this code.

`Sslac.Function("IN.$Tag",function(b,a){a=a||document;`

One thing I discovered, even though it says in the [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) that the `lang` argument is not required that it would error on `lang` being undefined. I tried to do the same thing with `onLoad` but I am still getting the error.

I am using React and we are using server side rendering. I did add a the NoSSR package to see if that would fix it but it still does not.

Below is the code I am using to setup the SDK.

```
     <Head>
      <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
          api_key: [API_KEY]
          lang: en_US
        ` }}
      />
    </Head>
```

Another thing to note is I did try [this](https://gist.github.com/pangeaware/bf82c82c807190f0ff28e90d46e5cd71) solution as well with the same results.

**Update**

This has to be a SSR thing. I can create the exact same app in create-react-app and in Nextjs, create-react-app is all ran client side, next is server side. Create-react-app works fine.

Here is the link to the magic for NextJS.
https://github.com/rileybracken/linkedin-test-next/blob/master/pages/index.js

Here is the link to the magic for Create React App.
https://github.com/rileybracken/linkedin-test-create-react-app/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: could the tag be `<script></script>` instead of `<script />`?

Comment: @AnthonyC I could try, but React will work with self closing tags. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: You are right about the self closing tag. I created a plunker and your example works for me, even without the `lang`. Maybe the error was thrown because the API was called before the initialization? It'd help if you can create a plunker so we can replicate the problem.

Comment: I am positive it has to do with server side rendering. I built a test create-react-app and it works fine. It is when I put it into SSR that it gets messed up.

Comment: Interesting. What do you see from the html source code? Does the script tag get rendered correctly?

Comment: @AnthonyC I have setup 2 github repos to look at, I added them to the original post.

Comment: I tested the Nextjs app in chrome, I was able to call the people API successfully without seeing any error

Comment: Yes, it works sometimes, that is where it is weird. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It usually doesn't work if you cmd-shift-r or if you open it in safe mode.

Comment: I have the same issue here.... :(

Comment: I had the same issue. After hours of trial and error I found the issue in my app was conflict with google signin. I changed async to defer on the google script and it magically fixed the linked script. e.g. <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" defer></script>

Answer (score 0):

Ok not that this solves the problem but I had to put a `onLoad` argument in. I said that I did this before, but I had to do it in front of the script that initializes the JavaScript SDK.

I don't know if it is a SSR specific issue, a React issue or that the Linkedin JavaScript SDK  docs are not correct. But this works for now.

```
    <Head>
      <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'function liInit() { return null; }' }} />
      <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
          api_key: [API_KEY]
          lang: en_US
          onLoad: liInit
        ` }}
      />
    </Head>
```

I am not going to accept this as the final answer since the documentation is off and this is more of a hack to get it to work.

Comment: Actually I lied, I am still having the problem, however it is less so now.